# Crystal Report Crosstab String Data

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a `datatable` that looks like this (all columns have `string` datatype)

```
firstCol   secondCol  thirdCol

1_str1     1_str2     5,1  
2_str1     2_str2     5
3_str1     3_str2     
....       ....       ....
```

note that on the thirdCol, some fields are blank.

as for the crystal report, I have used the cross-tab feature

```
Columns:                firstCol

Rows:                   secondCol

Summarized Fields:      thirdCol
```

The columns and rows are okay. The only problem that I have is the summarized fields.
As far as I have searched, it is only used for numeric data (correct me if I'm wrong).

I even created a sample datatable and bound it on the crystal report. Instead of `string`, it displays the "numeric" (or you may call it integer, decimal, etc) datatype which is not what I want. Is there any way to display it as a `string` ?

this is the actual datatable

[image: my datatable]

and this is the crystal report cross-tab output

[image: cross-tab]

nevermind the *total column and row* on the crystal report output. I just want to display "5,1" and "1" on the cross-tab, not the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can display the summarized field as a string. When you created the crosstab, the default summary function is `count()` which is what you're seeing. Instead, go into your crosstab, select your summarized field, and hit the 'Change Summary' button. Instead of count you can use minimum or maximum (interchangeably, since I'm guessing that you will ever only have on entry for each row/column combination).

Once that change has been made, "5,1" will display for HCC and "5" will display for Legionella on Feb 14, and all other summarized fields will be null.

Comment: thanks! I have seen that too, but I never thought that Maximum and Minimum would not return a number value. Thank you! Can i ask again if is it possible to remove the `Total` rows and column? I'll post another question if it is needed..

Comment: I just suppressed the total rows and columns.. now it's okay. :)